# TemplateSyntaxError 'apptags' is not a registered tag library

Tags: python, django, django-templates, web-development-server, django-custom-tags

I have made a custom template tag , in apptags.py file which is inside templatetag folder and templatetag folder is inside my application folder, with the following code

```
from django import template
import datetime
register=template.Library()
@register.simple_tag(name="get_date")
def get_date():
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return now
```

and im using it in my html file as

```
% load static %}
{% load apptags %}
{% get_date as today %}
<h2>Today is {{today}} </h2>
```

and it is showing the below error:

TemplateSyntaxError at /exam/show-test/
'apptags' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz

P.S :- Templatetag is a package as i've made a **init**.py file inside it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add your templatetags in your project `settings.py` file for Django to identify it.

Add this to entry to your `OPTIONS` of `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py` file:

```
'libraries':  {
                '<template_tag name>': '<App_name>.templatetags.<template_tag name>',
            }
```

Example:

```
'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'libraries':  {
                'dict_key': 'blogs.templatetags.dict_key',
            }
```

Comment: @Navya Thakur I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: Jetbrains has a nice example of this type of solution here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/custom-template-tags.html

Answer (score 0):

according to ***django documentions***:

> The app should contain a templatetags directory, at the same level as
> models.py, views.py, etc. If this doesn’t already exist, create it -
> don’t forget the **init**.py file to ensure the directory is treated
> as a Python package

in your case, folder name is templatetag that is wrong
so you should **rename** it to templatetags .
otherwise you should follow [@Ram](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68149498/16736500) answer as:

> Alternatively, template tag modules can be registered through the
> 'libraries' argument to DjangoTemplates. This is useful if you want to
> use a different label from the template tag module name when loading
> template tags. It also enables you to register tags without installing
> an application